# I am getting UTC time from response but it's not able to parse it into correct default system time zone

Tags: android

i am getting UTC time from response but it's not able to parse it into default system time zone. It's getting around 6 hour late time.
for example "2014-12-22T07:51:58-05:00" but my current time is "06:13PM".
But after converting above date/ time string into default date/ time, the final output is "01:21 PM" but i need "06:13PM". Any help will be appreciable.

My code is Here.

```
String dateString = "2014-12-22T07:51:58-05:00";
String newDateFormat = "";
String date = "";
long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
Date localTime = new Date(ts);

final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
final java.util.Date dateObj = sdf.parse(dateString);
final java.util.Date fromGMT = new Date(dateObj.getTime() +     TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(localTime.getTime()));
newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("KK:mm a").format(fromGMT);
date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy").format(fromGMT);
Log.d("newDateFormat:","newDateFormat:"+newDateFormat);
```

result should be "06:13PM". Thanks

Blockquote

Comment: Have you tried removing ':' from "2014-12-22T07:51:58-05:00" -> "2014-12-22T07:51:58-0500" and also changing "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

Comment: sorry @hoomi but it's not possible. it's dynamic response value, please suggest any practical and working way. thanks

Comment: Try changing your SimpleDateFormatter to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ" to include the TimeZone in your parsing

Comment: now i'm getting 00:29AM of 06:51PM. #hoomi